# Remove text without tags

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

I am trying to do a manual rendering of Django forms and it generates the code below, is there a way to get rid of the texts that do not have any HTML tags, a good example is the texts "Currently: " and "Change:" it is really difficult to style with CSS.

```
<div class="row align-center mb-0 text-center">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="fuzone mb-2">
        <div class="fu-text">
            <span><i class="mdi mdi-image-area"></i> Click here or drop files to upload</span>
        </div>

        Currently: 
        <a href="/media/realtor/download.jpeg">realtor/download.jpeg</a>
        <input type="checkbox" name="image-clear" id="image-clear_id">
        <label for="image-clear_id">Clear</label><br> 
        Change:
        
        <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" class="clearablefileinput form-control-file" id="id_image">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem ?

Comment: @usmanimtiaz is there a way to get rid of texts not in HTML tags?

Comment: But all text is inside of a tag, whether that's the `<body>` or some other element further down the DOM tree. How do define the text that should be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You are safe to highlight 'Currently:' and 'Change:' and delete them without affecting your code. :)

On the other hand, if you'd like to style them, you can wrap them in divs and assign them css styling by referencing their class names.
Imagine divs like physical boxes that hold content. Very rarely should anything not be in a div.